# jquery ui autocomplete event timing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to return a numeric id for a selection but display a customer name in words. I have a hidden field for the customer id and a text input for the display name. It sort of works but I'd prefer to improve the user experience.

An ajax request returns the customer list in the variable data which is used to build an array of objects, as per the docs:

```
values = [];
$.each(data, function(index, guest) {
    values.push({label: guest, value: index});
});
```

Then I bind autocomplete to the form field:

```
$( "#customer" + numRand ).autocomplete({
    source: values,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {      // set hidden field with index of selection
        $( "#customerId" + numRand ).val(ui.item['value']);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {      // restore word label to input field
        $( "#customer" + numRand ).val(ui.item['label']);
    }
});
```

The numRand is there to create semi-unique identifiers because in this application the form is loaded in a JQuery ui dialog and there's retention of values between instances otherwise.

<strike>I've tried using the *change* event instead of *close* but the result is the same.</strike>* When at least two letter have been typed into the form field the menu appears correctly, displaying names. When a name is selected the numerical index goes into the form field. When focus moves to any other part of the page (clicking on the background works) the numerical index is replaced by the customer name, as desired. I want the name displayed initially as well.

Any suggestions as to how to get the name to display on select? (I have tried putting it in that handler but it's immediately overwritten by the id which stays there when focus moves).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

*EDIT - I was wrong, the *close* event, like the *select* event, gets overridden by the built-in method.

UPDATE: The solution is simple: use the *select* event and override the built-in method by returning false:

```
$( "#customer" + numRand ).autocomplete({
    source: values,
     minLength: 2,
     select: function (event, ui) {      
        $( "#customerId" + numRand ).val(ui.item['value']);
        $( "#customer" + numRand ).val(ui.item['label']);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Might want to put together a http://jsfiddle.net example of your code working.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ydMNf/

Comment: It's clearer here: http://jsfiddle.net/ydMNf/5/

Comment: Solution can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ydMNf/6/

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer if you solve the issue, so it doesn't show up in unanswered anymore. :)

Comment: Thanks - I've answered and will accept when the system permits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: use the select event and override the built-in method by returning false:

```
$( "#customer" + numRand ).autocomplete({
   source: values,
   minLength: 2,
   select: function (event, ui) {      
      $( "#customerId" + numRand ).val(ui.item.value);
      $( "#customer" + numRand ).val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to PetersenDidIt and Kit Sunde for the guidance with my first question here.